# Angular 4: why can't I call a public function in my ngOnInit()?

Tags: angular

So I've got the following code in my ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit() {
$('#inputForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.uploadFormData();
});

$('#fileUpload').on('change', function() {
  const fileString = $('#fileUpload').val();
  const fileType = $('#fileUpload').prop('files')[0].type;

  if (fileType !== 'text/xml') {
    $('#message').html('File to upload must be an XML file!!!');
    if (!$('#message').hasClass('error')) {
      $('#message').addClass('error');
    }
  } else {
    $('#message').html('File to upload is an XML file!!!');
    if ($('#message').hasClass('error')) {
      $('#message').removeClass('error');
    }
    $('#message').addClass('correctFile');
  }
});
```

}

This will watch for the onchange event & when I submit my form. When I submit my  form, I want to call a public function that's outside of this ngOnInit(), and it looks like this:

```
public uploadFormdata(): void {
  const form = $('#inputForm').val();
  const files = ($('#fileUpload') as any).files;
  const formData = new FormData();
  const file = files[0];

  formData.append('tenant', form[0]);
  formData.append('title', form[1]);
  formData.append('file', file, file.name);
  this.uploadService.uploadForm(formData)
    .subscribe(res => this.fileUploaded(res));
}
```

Why won't "this.uploadFormData()" in my ngOnInit() work? It says "property 'uploadFormData' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'".

Comment: Really, the answers below are in principle correct. However, you should really look at your code more from an Angular perspective. The way you implemented this is in complete contradiction to how you should do this in Angular. You will encounter many more issues if you go this route.

Comment: I agree with @MikeOne, you should avoid using jQuery for dom manipulation

Answer (score 2):

Use the arrow function, so that `this` refers to your component's class. If you don't, this will refer to the DOM element on which you bound the event, i.e. the `inputForm` field

```
$('#inputForm').submit(e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.uploadFormData();
});
```

**Note**: you should really avoid using jQuery for manipulating the DOM, as angular is not aware of changes caused by jQuery.

Comment: Nvm I got it! It works now, why does using the arrow function make it work in this case?

Comment: @Tempuslight Because the arrow function will bind this to the current context (i.e. the component class in your case), whereas the `function` will bind this to the context of the object you bound the event to (.e. the input DOM element)

Answer (score 2):

Because, `this` context into your sumbit form refered the `$('#inputForm')` not the class of your component.
In your situation, you have to save your context `this` into variable

```
ngOnInit() {
  const $this = this;
  $('#inputForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $this.uploadFormData();
  });
  // ...
}
```

Or you should use arrow function:

```
  ngOnInit() {
      $('#inputForm').submit((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.uploadFormData();
      });
      // ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> View elements only load after " OnInit ", you can use   [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  $('#inputForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.uploadFormData();
  });
}
```

> Use [Element ref](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) instead of ordinary JavaScript/ jQuery selector